# DynamoDB requires some time until the data appears in query

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm creating new item in the database

```
val client: AWSAppSyncClient = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
    .context(applicationContext)
    .cognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(BasicCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(userPool))
    .awsConfiguration(config)
    .s3ObjectManager(S3ObjectManagerImplementation(s3Client))
    .build()

fun insertItem(){
   val userInput: CreateUserInput = CreateUserInput
            .builder()
            ....populate values....
            .build()
        client.mutate(CreateUserMutation.builder().input(userInput).build())
            .enqueue(callback)
}
```

after that I see success messagess from `callback` and new item appears in `AWS DB console`.

But when I make query request:

```
client.query(ListUsersQuery.builder().filter(getFilter()).build())
      .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.NETWORK_ONLY)
      .enqueue( GraphQLCall.Callback....)
```

I'm not able to see item I added for some time. Request works fine only after few minutes item were inserted.

Is there any way to fetch actual data from `DynamoDB`?

Comment: Mutations go into an offline queue so I’d maybe look at logcat to see that the network writes arre happening. Often network issues in an emulator will agressively block

Comment: @NaderDabit Thank you! Seems you are right. I've made some tests and for now able to reproduce on emuliator only. I'll do more research.  As I understand cached mutations works same way and if there is networks issues and cache data not synced yet query returns previous cached state.

Comment: @NaderDabit  yep this is an answer :) Thanks, it is good to know about this.

Comment: seems not working on some samsung devices. and there is no network issues in the log